# Filter Multiple fields react

Tags: reactjs, filter

I have a user list table and single search textbox, I'm able to search the list by name. How can I make that searchbox to search by name, mobile email etc.

code to search by name.

```
 let filteredList =mapSP && mapSP.filter(
      (usr) => {
        return (usr.sp_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())
        ) !== -1;
      }
    );
```

Comment: provide user list array for better answer

Comment: user list come from mapStateToProps as follows

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    mapSP: state.firestore.ordered.users
   
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can just expand your filter like so:

```
let filteredList = mapSP && mapSP
    .filter(usr => {
        const normalizedSearchString = search.toLowerCase();
        return usr.sp_name.toLowerCase().includes(normalizedSearchString) 
            || usr.sp_mobile.includes(normalizedSearchString) 
            || usr.sp_email.includes(normalizedSearchString);
    });
```